# Why does the ammeter reading change in this way?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

#### Question:

> [image]
>
> Without calculation, state what happens, if anything, to the reading of ammeter $A1$ if:
>
> 1. The $2 \ \Omega$ resistor $R1$ is shorted out with a thick piece of wire
> 2. The piece of wire is removed and the $3 \ \Omega$ resistor $R3$ is removed

#### Answers:

> 1. Stays the same
> 2. Decreases

---

I'm new to circuits and I don't know how they arrived at these answers.

In **1.**, how does the reading stay the same if some resistance is removed in the branch opposite to the ammeter $A1$? Doesn't that increase the current going through the second branch, hence decreasing the reading on the ammeter's branch?

And in **2.**, why exactly will the reading decrease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In **1.**, how does the reading stay the same if some resistance is
> removed in the branch opposite to the ammeter $A1$?

The reading stays the same because the voltage across the parallel combination of $R3$ and $R4$ in series with the ammeter is the constant voltage of the ideal battery.

> And in **2.**, why exactly will the reading decrease?

The parallel combination of **R3** and **R4** is $2 \ \Omega$. The current per Ohms law for an ideal ammeter is then $12 \div 2 = 6 \ A$. If $R3$ is opened the resistance in series with the ammeter is greater ($6 \ \Omega$). The current is then $12 \div 6 = 2 \ A$ which is less.